# How are Servlet url mappings in web.xml used?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a web.xml file with content:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mycompany.test1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mycompany.test2</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried requests

```
.../path/test/abc 
.../path/test
```

Both requests are processed by Servlet2. Why?

**UPDATE**

Thank you guys for your help.
I realised that behaviour depends on order of servlet-mapping declaration.
I tried this web.xml

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mycompany.test1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mycompany.test2</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mycompany.test3</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet4</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mycompany.test4</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet4</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

results:

```
.../path/test/abc - servlet2
.../path/test/ - servlet2
.../path/test - servlet2

.../path/abc - servlet3
.../path/ - servlet4
.../path - servlet4
```

Comment: Maybe you are not running the current version of your web application. Are you using any IDE? How do you deploy?

Comment: /path/test fits in the /path/test/* rule, they are in conflict.

Comment: it looks like you have commented a part of code by mistake ..... check /*</url-pattern></servlet-mapping> .... 
is not commented... well I might be wrong but that is what you copied above right..

Comment: @AurA I think that is just Stack Overflow guessing the code snippet is Java.

Comment: @AurA Given that it is XML the comment certainly won't be with `/*`

Comment: @benzonico yes you are right /* */ comment is not allowed in XML

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl I've fixed up the syntax highlighting - for reference you can force a code block to be treated as a particular language by preceding it with `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` (or `lang-java` or whatever).

Comment: @Ian Roberts Thanks, Ian.

Comment: @wfr - could you edit your question to remove/clarify the UPDATE part. What you say there is not right. The order of the mappings is **irrelevant**. I lost quite a few hours with the assumption that your UPDATE was the solution to your problem. It perhaps is, but just by accident. Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From Servlet 3.0 [specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html), this is how the web container must locate the servlet after receiving a request (emphasis mine):

> The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the
>   request object  minus the context path and the path parameters. The
>   URL path mapping rules  below are used in order. **The first successful
>   match is used with no further matches  attempted**:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path  of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>      servlet.
> 2. **The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done  by stepping down the path tree a directory
>      at a time, using the ’/’ character as a  path separator. The longest
>      match determines the servlet selected.**
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet  container will try to match a servlet that handles
>      requests for the extension. An  extension is defined as the part of
>      the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will  attempt to serve content appropriate for the
>      resource requested. If a "default"  servlet is defined for the
>      application, it will be used. Many containers provide an  implicit
>      default servlet for serving content.
>
> The container must use case-sensitive string comparisons for matching.

You should also look the specification of mappings (given below):

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define  mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a `‘/’` character and ending with a `‘/*’` suffix
>     is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `‘*.’` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string `("")` is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to
>     the  application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>     `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is `’/’` and
>     the servlet path and context path is  empty string `(““)`.
> - A string containing only the `’/’` character indicates the "default"
>     servlet of the  application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path  and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only

Let us look at examples now. Consider the following set of mappings:

```
Path Pattern            Servlet
/foo/bar/*              servlet1
/baz/*                  servlet2
/catalog                servlet3
*.bop                   servlet4
```

The following behavior would result:

```
Incoming Path           Servlet Handling Request
/foo/bar/index.html     servlet1
/foo/bar/index.bop      servlet1
/baz                    servlet2
/baz/index.html         servlet2
/catalog                servlet3
/catalog/index.html     “default” servlet
/catalog/racecar.bop    servlet4
/index.bop              servlet4
```

Note that in the case of `/catalog/index.html` and `/catalog/racecar.bop`, the 
servlet mapped to `“/catalog”` is not used because the match is not exact.

Now coming to your problem :)

`/path/test` belongs to the 5th point of specification of mappings. Which means only the paths ending in `/path/test` will target `servlet1`.

However `/path/test/*` qualifies for the first point of the same specification. This means that:

`.../path/test` will be handled by `servlet1` and

`.../path/test/abc` will be handled by `servlet2`

Which was verified by me in a test application.

Comment: @wfr, why did you accept this reply for the answer?  It seems to disagree with your observation that servlet2 handled /path/test.

Comment: Thanks. You solved my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522888/how-does-the-getservletmapping-affects-the-url-in-spring-webmvc

Answer (score 1):

Your paths conflict.

Both of your paths mean the same, the '/*' doesn't make any difference.
Apparently then when you try your path, the last match (servlet2) is executed.

You usually put in a path with the Servlet name, like for example:

```
/path/test/servlet1
/path/test/servlet2
```