# Spring MVC configure url-pattern

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I try to configure simple Controller.

I have:
in **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="/index.jsp">
                <ref bean="mainPage"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="mainPage" class="ru.mypack.TBController" />
```

here is my **Controller**:

```
public class TBController extends AbstractController {

@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("It is here");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    return model;
}}
```

I run in on Tomcat 6 and in this configuration it (/index.jsp) works perfect!
But if I change url-pattern like this

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

it returns 404 accessing /index.jsp
I see "It is here" in console, it means url-pattern works fine but ModelAndView doesn't get initialized
Strange thing is that it looks like he tries to access empty resource
(Chrome dysplays me "HTTP Status 404 - ")

Please, help me to understand what is going on.. May be I missed something in url-pattern specification?

**UPD:**
Thanks to Pavel Horal, the solution has been found.
I just replaced my url-pattern in web.xml with

```
<url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
```

And now it responds by /test/index.jsp

Comment: Please take a look at this thread. It should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385596/servlet-mapping-web-xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring is working with the information how the servlet mapping is defined. If you are using suffix mapping (`*.something`), then Spring uses just the first part (without the suffix). This means you shuold map just `/index` in your url-pattern (without the suffix).

JavaDoc in Spring's `UrlPathHelper#getPathWithinServletMapping` gives a better description what is being used in the mapping process:

> Return the path within the servlet mapping for the given request, i.e.
>   the part of the request's URL beyond the part that called the servlet,
>   or "" if the whole URL has been used to identify the servlet.
>
> Detects include request URL if called within a RequestDispatcher
>   include.
>
> E.g.: servlet mapping = "/test/*"; request URI = "/test/a" -> "/a".
>
> E.g.: servlet mapping = "/test"; request URI = "/test" -> "".
>
> E.g.: servlet mapping = "/*.test"; request URI = "/a.test" -> "".

Comment: Thank you, now that's clear! I promise, next time I'll read JavaDoc more carefully :)

Comment: Well this particular JavaDoc is not easy to find. This is internal Spring class. However what I love about Spring is, that even internal classes are well defined and documented (unlike in many other frameworks).

Comment: @PavelHoral Could you help me with this question? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522888/how-does-the-getservletmapping-affects-the-url-in-spring-webmvc