# How does the `getServletMapping()` affects the URL in Spring WebMVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

I use the following code to map the `DispatcherServlet` to `/` URL:

```
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[] {"/"};      
}
```

And I can visit my `@Controller` handler method with the following URL:

> http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/controller1/method1

Then I changed the `DispatcherServlet` mapping to below:

```
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[] {"/app"};    //<=== HERE    
}
```

I expected the new URL below should work, but actually not.

> http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/**app**/controller1/method1

It always gives me `404` error.

I tried the following 2 ways to configure the `Controller`, neither works.

Option 1:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("controller1")
public class Controller1 {
    @RequestMapping("method1")
    public String Method1(Model model) {
     ...
    }
```

Option 2:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app/controller1") //<--- Still doesn't work.
public class Controller1 {
    @RequestMapping("method1")
    public String Method1(Model model) {
     ...
    }
```

Why? How does the `getServletMappings()` affect the final URL?

### ADD 1

Strange enough. If I write `/app/*` instead of just `/app`. It works. But if so, how could `/` work at all? It should be `/*` if the logic is *consistent*.

But as I tried, if I use `/*`, the servlet engine seems malfunctioning, it even failed to parse the `jsp` page. Below is what I see in my browser. How could the JSP page source be displayed?

> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>   ROOT: ${root}!
>
> WEB: ${servlet}!

### ADD 2

My WebMVC configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {com.its.cloud.web.BeaconClassForComponentScan.class})
public class ITSCloudWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletApplicationContextExplorer servletApplicationContextExplorer() {
        return new ServletApplicationContextExplorer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

The structure of the package that contains my controllers:

[image]

By using the `BeaconClassForComponentScan` as the marker class for `@ComponentScan` annotation, I believe the `web`, `interfaces`, `impls` and `controllers` pacakges will all be scanned.

### Ref:

Maybe a related thread, but still not fixing the issue: [Spring MVC configure url-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988689/spring-mvc-configure-url-pattern)

Comment: Check your component scan, it seems your controllers are not registered as spring beans.

Comment: @px5x2 Sorry, I forget to paste the `@Controller` annotation in my code snippet. I do have it in my code. The component scan should be alright. I updated my question.

Comment: Could you also provide your web mvc configuration?

Comment: @px5x2 Added the webmvc configuration class to my question.

Comment: Could you include your controllers' package as `basePackages` in `@ComponentScan` annotation? Like `@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.foo", ...)`

Comment: @px5x2 Still the same issue. And I updated my question.

Comment: This has very little to do with Spring MVC. A servlet mapping is not a path prefix. It has rules that a Servlet container must follow. Those are explained in the linked question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks! Indeed. It's part of the Servlet spec. I am new to Servlet technology. That link does help.