# Spring MVC 404 even though URL is mapped

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've been trying to setup a Spring MVC controller but when I try to make a GET request, I get a 404 error.

I created a working test example here: https://github.com/Jardo-51/zk-spring-mvc-test

When I run the application on Tomcat and try to make a GET request to: http://localhost:8080/zk-spring-mvc-test/api/v0/foo, I get a 404 error and the logs say:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/zk-spring-mvc-test/api/v0/foo] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher-api'`
```

I've been trying to fix it according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577235/2468620), and found out that the controller is mapped correctly because the logs on startup say:

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/zk-spring-mvc-test/api/v0/foo],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.jardoapps.zkspringmvctest.controllers.FooController.method()
```

The app uses ZK framework which needs its own servlets so maybe there is a conflict with the `DispatcherServlet`. Please see my example app for more details (it contains only the necessary code).

Here is the [web.xlm](https://github.com/Jardo-51/zk-spring-mvc-test/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) (Spring context and MVC config are at the top).

Here is the [controller class](https://github.com/Jardo-51/zk-spring-mvc-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jardoapps/zkspringmvctest/controllers/FooController.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply replace `@RequestMapping("zk-spring-mvc-test/api/v0/foo")` with `@RequestMapping("/v0/foo")` in your `FooController` class.**

The reason is that the path that you specify into the `@RequestMapping` annotation is the part of the request's URL beyond the part that called the servlet.

You defined `DispatcherServlet`'s mapping as:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So we have **`zk-spring-mvc-test`** that is the context root (this is deploy dependent), **`/api/`** that calls the Spring `DispatcherServlet`, and finally **`/v0/foo`** that should be mapped by your controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v0/foo")
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> method() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("OK");
    }
}
```

You can see [Spring MVC configure url-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16988689/3260495) for further information.