# View Resolver and Controller mapping in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

How View resolver determine which controller to load when more than one `@Controller` exist.

I am learning Spring from Scratch, as per my instructor she says, we need to have only one Controller class with `@Controller` annotation. what if I have more than one class with a `@Controller` annotation and how `ViewResolver` determines which controller class to load, as Spring is singelton and only one controller class exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please read how to ask a question.  Post some code and highlight the specific issues you are facing.  If this is a homework question then you should really be asking your instructor how to do it.

Comment: Your basics are really weak.
First, think before you ask/speak. View Resolver, as the name specifies, just resolves views or simply provides the 'visual layout page' like .jsp files.
And it is DispatcherServlet which determines the controller based on the 'path' as depicted by RequestMapping annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not view resolver that determines which controller to load: it is instead the DispatcherServlet that does that. What View resolver does is to match String-based view names to actual View types.
In order to match more than one controller you can use [servlet mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385596/servlet-mapping-web-xml) to define services and endpoints.

If you browse to http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html, you will find an in depth description of how things work. 
[image: structure]

Answer (score 0):

It does not determine which @Controller to load, it loads all @Controller which is configured scanned packages