# Multiple Http Servlets string path mapping

Tags: java, servlets

I'm want to map these two different servlets (using addServletWithMapping):

"/soccerapp/teams/*"

"/soccerapp/teams/*/players

but the second is obviously never reached, is any other special char that I can use in the string path to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard in the middle of the path is not evaluated. You can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386616/1630604 for a complete description how the path are evaluated.

Anyway, you cannot map two Servlet to one URL.